# Wordpress: How to redirect old links after changing permalink structure?

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect, permalinks

I have changed my permalink structure in WordPress.

Can a plugin help me redirect old links to the new?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Redirection](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) works for this, however for it to automatically detect the permalink changes, you'll probably have to revert the permalinks, install Redirection, and then change to the desired permalinks again.

If this isn't adequate, you can add them manually, and it has tools to help you find 404's that you were not aware of.

Comment: Wow, Redirection seems good. Actually, I need to change my permalinks from `category/id` to `category/id-postname`. And I know if I change this, all my old links will be broken. So what can I do ? To install Redirection, and ?

Comment: All you have to do is install Redirection, then change your permalinks. Redirection automatically deals with the redirects.

Comment: Nope, I just tried ! And redirection not add automatically the new url. I get a error 404. I need to add the old url to the new url **manually** (I have more than 100 posts lol)

Comment: Tested it personally, worked perfectly. Ensure the plugin is turned on, for starters.

Comment: If it's not working for you (and I have no idea why, it's probably operator error or some config bug on your server) then there's a myriad of other, similar options. Here's [just one](http://www.clickonf5.org/wordpress/change-permalink-wordpress-301-redirect-backlinks/7035).