# Permalink issue on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I changed my Permalink structure 1 year ago to `/%postname%/zippy`

Now I want to change it back to `/%postname%/`,  But when I do this, there is no redirection from **/zippy to posts.

Thank you for helping me out of this mess.

Comment: This might help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960948/wordpress-how-to-redirect-old-links-after-changing-permalink-structure

Answer (score 0):

This plugin http://tutslog.com/tutorials/plugin-wordpress-supermalink-139.html may can't help you fix this issue. But It helps you avoid issues like that.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.