# changing permalink gives 404 error for old links

Tags: php, wordpress

I have changed the permalink from **Post name** to **Custom Structure**.

Earlier my blog links were like `www.website.com/blog-post-link` i want to change that to `www.website.com/my-articles/blog-post-link` so my **custom structure** permalinks looks as following and it does give me what I want

`https://website.com/my-articles/%postname%/`

However all the old links are now giving 404 error `www.website.com/blog-post-link`

What can I do so that old links get redirected to the new link and does not give page not found error. I have 100s of blog post, i hope i dont have to manually do a redirect for each blog post.

I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960948/wordpress-how-to-redirect-old-links-after-changing-permalink-structure) but it does not seem to work for me

Comment: Are you using Wordpress ?

Comment: yes, i am using wordpress

Comment: Normally wordpress will generate a new .htacces for you automatically (and it should work). Can you check if wordpress can write the .htaccess? You will get an error if wordpress cant write the .htaccess and inform you to edit it manually with the provided code.

Comment: yes the .htaccess gets generated just fine. the new links work just fine. its only the old links that i need help in redirecting to the new links

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite `.htaccess` rule

```
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</ifmodule>
```

Comment: can you please explain this more? how is this going to add `my-articles` for the blog post URL?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem in the past with one of my WordPress sites, when I had to add an extra '/en/' to the permalink ( Like this - http://example.com/xyz to http://example.com/en/xyz ). I have used a plugin called Velvet Blues to tackle the issue.

All you have to do is just enter the old and new permalink schemes.

Here is the link.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/

PS :
Make sure that your htaccess setup works properly.

Comment: this is not what i need, this is going to update the URL in database FOR ALL LINKS.... as i mentioned i need my blog link to change only